# When must we use implicit and explicit operators in C#?

Tags: c#, operators, implicit, explicit

What is the usage of these operators?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically when you want to provide conversions between types. LINQ to XML provides good examples... There's an *implicit* conversion from string to XName, so you can write:

```
XName name = "element";
```

but there's an *explicit* conversion from `XAttribute` to `int` (and many other types) so you have to include a cast in your code:

```
int value = (int) element.Attribute("age");
```

Think very carefully before providing implicit conversions - they're *rarely* a good idea; LINQ to XML uses them to great effect, but they can be confusing. Even explicit user-defined conversions can surprise the unwary reader.

Comment: Nearly most of the times I avoid using them as a library designer (unless I am sure they will not be misused and complained).

Answer (score 4):

They are used when doing [operator overloading](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Csharp_implicit_operator.aspx). Here's a link to a [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28VS.71%29.aspx).